# ScrollView with ViewPager can't scroll xml file in that ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, view, android-viewpager

I have a ScrollView in that I have a ViewPager with a PagerSlidingTabStrip. In the ViewPager I have a xml file  which contains some TextViews with long texts in it. The problem is that the scrollview don't scroll to the end where the last TextViews are of the second xml file are.

First xml with viewPager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/recipe_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5.80" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipe_linearLayout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="18"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" >
            </com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second xml file with the TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5.80" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipe_linearLayout_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="INGREDIENTS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ingLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingTV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.11"
                android:maxLines="20"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/verylongtext"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingLinearLayout"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="DESCRIPTION"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/descLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descTV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.11"
                android:maxLines="20"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/verylongtext"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks when I scroll to the bottom:
[image]

And this is how it should look:
[image]

I can not find out why it cuts the view and why is it not possible to scroll down until the whole second xml file is displayed?

I am using this ViewPager lib: [github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions)